# There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:exception. in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, datacontractserializer

I am calling my WCF method from the portal application.

My WCF setup is as follows:

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILogging
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ErrorExceptionInformation))]
            void LogException(ErrorExceptionInformation exception);
        }


    public class Logging : ILogging
        {
            public void LogException(ErrorExceptionInformation exception)
            {

                LogProviderManager.Default.WriteLog(exception.Application, exception.Exception, true, exception.Category);
            }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class ErrorExceptionInformation
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string Application { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public Exception Exception { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string Category { get; set; }

        }
```

and this is how i invoke in the portal application:

```
ErrorExceptionInformation information = new ErrorExceptionInformation
                {
                    Exception = errorToLog,
                    Application = Models.Constants.ErrorLog.ErrorLocation,
                    Category = Models.Constants.ErrorLog.AdminPortalEnvironmentName
                };

                new LoggingClient().LogException(information);
```

However i keep getting the following error:
Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can do this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILogging
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypeHelper))] // << -- change this
    void LogException(ErrorExceptionInformation exception);
}

static class KnownTypeHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type> knownTypes =
            new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type>();

        knownTypes.Add(typeof(ErrorExceptionInformation));
       // knownTypes.Add(typeof(... any others....));

        return knownTypes;
    }
}
```

> Update

OR put the attribute on the interface instead of the operation contract:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ErrorExceptionInformation))]
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILogging
{
    [OperationContract]            
    void LogException(ErrorExceptionInformation exception);
}
```

Comment: i am not relly getting the gyst of it, as its the same as using [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ErrorExceptionInformation))]

Comment: One would think, but the reason I do it this way is because your way gives me the same error.

Comment: @babuji This prompted me to look into this further, the attribute goes on the interface not the operation contract if you use that version.